# Storing the image in folder with unique name and path in database

Tags: php, image, storage, directory

I am getting the picture encoded data in the php file through json. My requirement is to store that images in server in one folder provided each image should be assigned a unique name. I am getting lot of doubts on how to store the image in a folder with unique name and then again the path of the image is stored in the database. I have seen couple of StackOverflow questions and online sources, but couldn't get them clearly. This question seems simple to the ones who work on PHP. But as a newbie in php and as an Android developer, I am unable to understand that less-detailed answers. So, I would really appreciate if someone can help me with code snippets and explanation. I tried to keep my explanation of question and code with comments as clear as I can. If there are any mistakes, please go easy.The following is the code that I tried and got stuck at some points. Thanks in advance..

```
    <?php
    $response = array();

    // check for required fields
    if (isset($_POST['mailid']) && isset($_POST['category']) && isset($_POST['description']) && isset($_POST['contactNum']) && isset($_POST['lookingto']) && isset($_POST['image'])) {

        $usermail = $_POST['mailid'];
        $category = $_POST['category'];
        $description = $_POST['description'];
        $contactNum = $_POST['contactNum'];
        $lookingto = $_POST['lookingto'];
        $base=$_POST['image'];

        $binary=base64_decode($base);

        $folder = "images/"; // This is my folder "images" in which pics have to be stored.

        $file = fopen('storepic.jpg', 'wb');  // Here I have to give name dynamically to each pic provided that should be unique. Here I mentioned pic name as storepic.jpg, a static name.

        fwrite($file, $binary);

        fclose($file);

        // include db connect class
        require_once __DIR__ . '/db_connect.php';

        // connecting to db
        $db = new DB_CONNECT();

        // mysql inserting a new row
        $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO details(usermail, category, description, contactnumber,posting_for) VALUES('$usermail', '$category', '$description','$contactNum','$lookingto')");

//// Even after giving dynamic name how can we store the path of the dynamic named image into database in the above query. For that what should be done here..

        // check if row inserted or not
        if ($result) {
            // successfully inserted into database
            $response["success"] = 1;

            // echoing JSON response
            echo json_encode($response);
        } else {
            // failed to insert row
            $response["success"] = 0;


            // echoing JSON response
            echo json_encode($response);
        }
    } else {

        $response["success"] = 0;


        // echoing JSON response
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
    ?>
```

Even in other php file I am retrieving the data by select query. I am able to get the normal data what I inserted could get it on Android client side app. But then again how to get the image from the path for later converting into base64 encoded data and then echoing as json response..

**NOTE:-** My UI is not form. It's an Android UI..

Comment: Exactly how are you sending this image to the server? standard php file uploads go through the $_FILES array, **NEVER** $_POST. As well, don't assign your name until AFTER you've inserted the data into the db. you can then use the last_insert_id() as the filename to use, guaranteeing it's unique.

Comment: What you are doing is terribly insecure.  You are **wide open** to SQL injection attacks and you **will be hacked** if you haven't been already.  Learn to use prepared queries with PDO or similar to avoid this problem entirely.

Comment: @MarcB OP probably using the fancy data uri upload :)

Comment: Make a backup of your database, then go to your form and enter the following for an email address: `sql@inject.ed'; DROP TABLE details; --'`

Comment: for unique names you can use e.g. `md5(microtime())`

Comment: @vlcekmi3: that's not unique. highly unlikely to collide, but definitely NOT unique. far safer to use the auto_increment id from whatever table the data's being saved into instead.

Comment: To expand on @Brad, you'll want to use mysql_real_escape_string() to prevent SQL injections.  For example: `$usermail = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['mailid']);`

Comment: @MarcB I can't use $_files here because my UI is not a form to upload a pic.  It's an android UI where user can take a pic from the camera of the android device on the fly in the application and send his details with image also included in that. I think I should have highlighted that thing, because you guys might not have seen, as I mentioned in the question. That's the reason I am converting the image(bitmap in android) to base64  data which inturn included in the json object. So at php side I am getting it with $_POST. Can you suggest me based on that or any other way?

Comment: @jmgardn2, That's not what I was suggesting.  If you use prepared queries, it becomes a non-issue.  If you resort to escaping data every time, there will inevitably be a time when you forget, making your site vulnerable.  It only takes one mistake to allow outside folks into where they shouldn't be.

Comment: @Brad You might be right, because I don't much about PHP. So, I followed this approach which was somewhat easily understood by me. But if you can suggest the secured ways along with the answer to my qestion, I would be pleased. Thank you.

Comment: @Jack Please see the comment above and Note in my question..

Comment: @vlcekmi3 Please see the comment above and Note in my question.

Comment: @jmgardn2 Please see the comment above and Note in my question.

Comment: @MarcB last_insert_id is almost a solution but there is a problem. What if in the time of calling last_insert_id after inserting the query in db , another insert takes place ?

Comment: @Brad I agree, prepared queries are the best route, however that would involve converting his script to PDO which may be a much larger endeavor than it may appear. I was just giving another option which may require less change to his code.

Comment: @MD.SahibBinMahboob, The ID returned from last insert ID is for that specific connection.  If you have only made one insert, you can be sure that the last inserted ID will be yours, regardless of other users doing inserts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    // A very basic field validation. You should really use mysqli* or PDO*.

    $fields = array(
        'usermail'    => 'mailid',
        'category'    => 'category',
        'description' => 'description',
        'contactNum'  => 'contactNum',
        'lookingto'   => 'lookingto',
        'binary'      => 'base',
    );
    $okay = true;
    foreach($fields as $var => $field)
    {
         if (!isset($_POST[$field]))
             $okay = false;
         if ('binary' == $var)
             ${$var} = base64_decode($_POST[$field]);
         else
             ${$var} = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[$field]);
    }
    if (!$okay)
    {    
        $response["success"] = 0;
        Header("Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8");
        die(json_encode($response));
    }

    $folder = "images/"; // This is my folder "images" in which pics have to be stored.

    $file   = tempnam($folder, 'image');

    $fp     = fopen($file, 'w');
    fwrite($file, $binary);    
    fclose($file);

    /* BUT WHAT IF THE FILE IS NOT JPEG?
       Then you use GD library and do:

       $gd = ImageCreateFromString($binary);
       if (!$gd)
       {
           // Abort. Image was invalid.
       }
       // Here you can even resize it.
       ImageJPEG($gd, $file, 75); // Quality 75%; useable values from 40 to 100
       ImageDestroy($gd);
    */

    ...

    $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO details(usermail, category, description, contactnumber,posting_for) VALUES('$usermail', '$category', '$description','$contactNum','$lookingto')");

    // I assume that the above table has an unique ID. So we retrieve it
    $lastid = mysql_insert_id(); 

    rename($file, $newfile = sprintf("%s/img%08d.jpg", $folder, $lastid));
```

Above, you *do not need a column name for the file name* since the name is the same as the row ID: if ID is 1234, the image is `images/img00001234.jpg`.

Otherwise you have to issue another query:

```
    UPDATE details SET filename='$newfile' WHERE id = $lastid;
```

### To retrieve

In all cases you'll receive some information about the row to retrieve; at a minimum its ID, or anyway some conditions you can plug into a `WHERE`. If, for example, you get the user email (and it is a unique key), you'll use `WHERE email='...'`.

So you will be able to issue a `SELECT * FROM details WHERE...` and among these details you will find either the ID, or the `filename` field.

In the first case you've got enough to *build* the filename and do not even need the database query, but **remember that anyone knowing the ID can now access the image**, this may be harmless or even desired (e.g. user public avatar image) but sometimes it might not be.

```
$lastid  = (int)$_REQUEST['id'];
$newfile = sprintf("%s/img%08d.jpg", $folder, $lastid);
```

Note that the syntax is the same as above; the `(int)` cast is to remember that this is user-supplied information and could contain all sorts of malicious crud.

In the second case you'll issue a `WHERE` and fetch either the ID or directly the filename field from the retrieved tuple.

Having the image path, you can send it to the user... if the image is there. Just checking.

```
if (!is_readable($newfile))
{
    Header('HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found')
    readfile('/path/to/beautiful/error-page.html');
    die();
}
// if you are really paranoid, or want to support different quality images,
// you can $gd = imageCreateFromJPEG($newfile); here, check it succeeded or
// send 404 / 500 error if it failed, manipulate $gd and send it along with
// ImageJPEG($gd, '', $quality); instead of the readfile() down there. With
// this approach, you'll better not send Content-Length, though. This makes
// image DOWNLOADS more awkward (you don't see "104K of 1.3M downloaded").

Header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
Header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($newfile));
readfile($newfile);
die();
```

...and that's it. In the HTML source calling the above, you might have:

```
<img class="avatar" src="images.php?id=<?php echo $details['id']; ?>" />
```

(the PHP generating that HTML *needs* to access the database and fetch `$details`, of course).

There are other setups that allow the "calling" PHP to save the database tuple information in the _GET parameters in a protected way, so that even if the user sees that the image was retrieved with

```
image.php?id=1234
```

and knows that Bob has ID 7654, still she can't retrieve the image by changing 1234 into 7654, but I don't know whether this is of interest to someone.

With Web browsers, setting the content is enough. Using Internet Explorer you might need the file to end in `.jpg`, and this in turn might require using a URL Rewriting scheme.

Comment: +1 for your answer. It was strange to me because my question got so many comments and they were arguing, but no one tried to answer. Thank you very much for your answer. But I do have some doubts, what should be done if I need to retrieve the file whenever needed (for this I need to have the details of image inserted into database if I am not wrong) etc., Can you please suggest me?

Comment: ...additionally, most of the comments you got were actually *very good advice*, worth considering even if in this one case you feel they're not useful. You'll notice that I *did* implement most of those suggestions, even if I did not take it so far as rewrite mysql_ into PDO.

Comment: Yeah. I agree. Their comments are informative and yet deep which I couldn't understand as a beginner in PHP. I usually work on Android. But sure I will update my code according to secured methods later. But for now I am trying to make it work at least. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
    package com.example.test_image_save;

    import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
    import java.io.FileInputStream;
    import java.io.IOException;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.ContentValues;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.database.Cursor;
    import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
    import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
    import android.net.Uri;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.os.Environment;
    import android.provider.MediaStore;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.ImageView;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    protected static TextView textView;
    protected static ImageView image1, image2;
    protected Button get_image, save_image, read_image;
    private String selectedImagePath;
    private static final int SELECT_PICTURE = 1;
    String DB_NAME = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/test.db";
    String TABLE_NAME = "mytable";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    image1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    image2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

    get_image = (Button) findViewById(R.id.get_image);
    get_image.setOnClickListener(this);

    save_image = (Button) findViewById(R.id.save_image);
    save_image.setOnClickListener(this);

    read_image = (Button) findViewById(R.id.read_image);
    read_image.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    public void onClick(View v) {

    int id = v.getId();
    switch (id) {

    case R.id.get_image:
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        startActivityForResult(
                Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"),
                SELECT_PICTURE);
        break;

    case R.id.save_image:
        createTable();
        saveInDB();
        break;

    case R.id.read_image:
        readFromDB();
        break;
    default:
        break;

    }
    }

    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == SELECT_PICTURE) {
            Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
            selectedImagePath = getPath(selectedImageUri);
            System.out.println("Image Path : " + selectedImagePath);
            image1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            image1.setImageURI(selectedImageUri);
        }
    }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public String getPath(Uri uri) {
    String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
    Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
    int column_index = cursor
            .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    return cursor.getString(column_index);
    }

    void createTable() {
    SQLiteDatabase myDb = openOrCreateDatabase(DB_NAME,
            Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);
    String MySQL = "create table if not exists "
            + TABLE_NAME
            + " (_id INTEGER primary key autoincrement, name TEXT not null, image BLOB);";
    myDb.execSQL(MySQL);
    myDb.close();
    }

    void saveInDB() {
    SQLiteDatabase myDb = openOrCreateDatabase(DB_NAME,
            Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);
    byte[] byteImage1 = null;
    String s = myDb.getPath();

    myDb.execSQL("delete from " + TABLE_NAME);          // clearing the table
    ContentValues newValues = new ContentValues();
    String name = "SachinImages";
    newValues.put("name", name);
    try {
        FileInputStream instream = new FileInputStream(selectedImagePath);
        BufferedInputStream bif = new BufferedInputStream(instream);
        byteImage1 = new byte[bif.available()];
        bif.read(byteImage1);
        newValues.put("image", byteImage1);
        long ret = myDb.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, newValues);
        if (ret < 0)
            textView.append("Error");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        textView.append("Error Exception : " + e.getMessage());
    }
    myDb.close();
    textView.append("\n Saving Details \n Name : " + name);
    textView.append("\n Image Size : " + byteImage1.length + " KB");
    textView.append("\n Saved in DB : " + s + "\n");
    Toast.makeText(this.getBaseContext(),
            "Image Saved in DB successfully.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    void readFromDB() {
    byte[] byteImage2 = null;
    SQLiteDatabase myDb;
    myDb = openOrCreateDatabase(DB_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);
    Cursor cur = myDb.query(TABLE_NAME, null, null, null, null, null, null);
    cur.moveToFirst();
    while (cur.isAfterLast() == false) {
        textView.append("\n Reading Details \n Name : " + cur.getString(1));
        cur.moveToNext();
    }

    // /////Read data from blob field////////////////////
    cur.moveToFirst();
    byteImage2 = cur.getBlob(cur.getColumnIndex("image"));
    setImage(byteImage2);
    cur.close();
    myDb.close();
    Toast.makeText(this.getBaseContext(),
            "Image read from DB successfully.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Toast.makeText(this.getBaseContext(),
            "If your image is big, please scrolldown to see the result.",
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    void setImage(byte[] byteImage2) {
    image2.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteImage2, 0,
            byteImage2.length));
    textView.append("\n Image Size : " + byteImage2.length + " KB");
    }

    }
```

Comment: The question seeks advice on how to do deal with image files in PHP, while your answer seems to show how todo this in an Android application.  In other words you answered the other question and your answer is inappropriate here. Another thing is that code-only answers, such as yours, tend to become seek-and-find games in which users can not deal with their problems efficiently. Adding good explanation to the answers always helps a lot and makes answers really great. Good luck and keep up the good work.